# Extending door jamb

Tags: doors

I recently put a new door into my existing front interior door opening, but it used a standard jamb size. The existing doorway was much wider, as the original owner kept the original wood siding on, plus added foam insulation and vinyl siding on-top of that. when I placed the new door in, I kept the back side of the door jamb flush with the inside of the door, so that the trim on the inside of the house would match back up (its an old plaster and lathe house, and didn't want to do a bunch of patch work on it).

Now, on the exterior side, there is a gap between where the doorjamb ends, and where the vinyl siding starts. To cover it from the front, I placed a 2x4 face-wise into the opening, leaving a smaller gap between the back of the 2x4 and the door jamb (about a 3/4" gap).

Since I don't want to remove the door and risk damaging the plaster on the interior, my plan is to put the jamb extension on the OUTSIDE of the door. I know this isn't conventional, but since the transition already sticks out the needed space, I think I can put the jamb on the exterior side flush enough so that I can put brick-moulding on it and cover up any gaps between the brick molding and the original siding. Since jchannel will butt right up next to the brick molding, followed by siding, I think that will work.

Considering the situation, is that the best option?

If I am able to include pictures, and some are needed to explain better, I will be happy to provide some.

Here are the pictures:

[image: This is looking outside, facing the left hand door jamb]

[image: Here is another picture. It's the best I can get you at the time as I am not at home. It's from the outside (door swings in)]

[image: Updated image]

Edited:: The after

https://flic.kr/p/22zhKqY

https://flic.kr/p/CYW452

https://flic.kr/p/22zhK4q

In the first two, I hadn't extended the original siding yet. The last one shows how it looks now (Except the second light is now mounted)

Comment: These aren't the best pictures, but.. the gap between the 2x4 in the front and the front of the jamb is the old wood siding. I am considering cutting the threshold flush at the bottom (where it tapers out around the current jamb), and adding the jamb to the front of it, thus filling in the gap (after I remove the 2x4 that wont be needed)

Comment: You're not asking a very specific question, but for me to answer with confidence I'd want to see the interior and exterior trim situations. I wonder why you can't put the extension jamb to the interior just as you've put the standard jamb in place.

Comment: IMHO, it is a big mistake holding the door frame to the inside. There is a part of the framing exposed more than needs to be from the jamb AND SILL falling short of the siding line.

Comment: @isherwood To answer your question, because the house is old, and it's no longer 100% square. It's easier to cover up a gap between the exterior and the back of the brick molding using the jchannel and siding than it is to cover up a gap between the wall and the interior trim. The way it sits now, the interior trim is flush with the wall like it should be.

Comment: @Jack I am not sure what you mean by holding it to the inside. The doorframe is attached to the rough opening of the home. The opening is standard size, they just never removed the original siding so the protruding part on the exterior is wider than the jamb. If I removed all the vinyl siding and then all the wood siding, then reattached the vinyl siding the door jamb would fit exactly how it should.

Comment: That doesn't clear it up for me. Maybe a photo would. You're putting a new jamb against something (presumably the back of the trim). Why can't the new *extended* jamb do the same?

Comment: @isherwood I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Are you referring to extending the jamb on the back-side so that it sits flush with the inside like the current jamb now does? The problem with doing that, is if the jamb extension isnt attached 100% correctly, and 100% square/flush, it won't sit flush on the interior. The door jamb now is manufactured straight and flush, so it's able to, but if the extension is installed not quite 100% it'll be noticeable on the inside.

Comment: Also, if memory serves me right, moving it to the inside requires relocating the hinges and strike plate, to which leaves me with a nasty existing set of holes I need to attempt to fill.

Comment: I don't think either of those things are true. Your extension jamb should fill the gap between the door (which was installed to the exterior) and the trim, whatever that entails. Hinges and strikes don't get moved. Again, photos might clear all this up for us.

Comment: To clarify the jamb should have been set to the outside flush with the rough framing, if there is rough framing beyond the jamb. The pictures don't show it but that 2 by 2 beyond the jamb is connected to something it should have gone out that far to eliminate the 2 by 2 on that side

Comment: @isherwood I am not sure how that would work? The hinges work now, because they are on the back of the jamb, and swing in. If I add the extension to the back of the jamb, where the hinges currently are, the entire door, including the hinges will need to be remounted to the extension, otherwise the door wouldn't be able to swing open.

Comment: @Jack Yes, that is what I am proposing doing. Mounting the extensions to the OUTSIDE facing part of the jamb instead of the inside. The idea is to bring the jamb out flush with the front of the old wood siding, which is what the 2x4 in the picture is attached to. My hope is that in putting the jamb extension on the front, it will clear the space and make it flush, but if it's not, any gaps will be between the back of the brick mold and the front of the wood siding, which will be covered by vinyl siding and jchannel

Comment: @Jack as an added, that's what I am proposing doing with the extension, so that I don't have the uneveness on the inside, where the wall and trim is. I think it'll be much easier to hide/conceal on the outside, where brick mold and vinyl siding/jchannel is, to hide any gaps.

Comment: The whole concern about having the jamb extension on the outside is that the sill of the door, the threshold that is, does not extend out as far as needed to protect that outside corner where the jamb extension meets the new exterior trim. It's more or less unprotected, water hits that surface and runs back into the framing and is not shed by the sill that would otherwise be there if the door was set to the outside with a jamb extension on the inside.

Comment: To clarify, what is the material beyond the edge of the sill that looks like the various layers of building paper possibly siding and or insulation? That needs to be capped of in a weatherproof fashion. The door sill usually does that, besides covering the transition from subfloor to wall.... This should have been addressed before the deck was built or the deck ledger was set to the door and the door was set. This is a recipe for decay.

Comment: @Jack Sorry about the late response, been busy. To answer your question, the picture you are referring to was BEFORE the deck was put on. That material was removed and there was flashing installed over the ledger that covered that, and went underneath and behind the current threshold. The way the threshold is now, the lip on it comes directly to the edge of the existing opening, like it would if it were moved forward more. Had I moved the frame forward, the threshold WOULD be sticking out past the frame at the bottom.

Comment: The trick is, the pan that was there is what would be protecting the framing beyond the door sill that you have now. The only way in my opinion to protect that area now if you choose to leave the door in the position that is now is to set a pan of flashing under the door sill extended up onto the sides of the framing a little. That would mean pulling the door again to do it at least to do it properly, since the door needs to be set in sealant on top of that pan once it is installed.

Comment: @Jack I think you are referring to the piece of wood under the threshold? Right now it appears next to the threshold where the gap is at, correct? Underneath the threshold and the size of the opening is a piece of aluminum flashing that the door, and the threshold sits on. Any water that gets between the threshold and that gap right now, hits the flashing and rolls down the front of it, onto the flashing for the ledger board. Once I get that gap filled, I was planning to run a bead if silicone where the extension and threshold meet. Is that what you were referring to? I marked the spot

Comment: Yes that is the spot I was referring to as well as obviously the one on the other side, if the flashing is also turned up on to the rough opening then those corners are protected. Good deal.

Comment: @Jack Yes, the flashing was cut and bent to form to the shape and sides of the opening underneath the threshold. I wanted to make sure it was good and protected so I didn't have to take the door apart again. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack- Here is an update of the work I did to finish off the door, including fixing the siding: I edited the original post.

Comment: Please provide and accept an answer or delete the question so it can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't an answer on this post, only a bunch of comments, so I had to create a new answer to it. I was able to get this by removing the old 2x4s and ripping down filler pieces to go in between the jamb and the exterior face boards. It turned out really nice and is all buttoned back up.